# Weekly view built on HTML/AJAX/JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Any recommendations on a good eye candy HTML/JQuery/AJAX weekly view that can be taken for use?

Comment: (reposting a reply [deleted] by another user as a comment): Please explain more, I am not understanding what you mean by "weekly view".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) is AJAX driven and has a weekly mode, seem to answer your requests.